# Inconsistency with Youtube-api Javascript and slow connections

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm building a website witch contains a 15 youtube embeds on 1 page, and I have a youtube-api javascript code witch plays them continuously, and changes a class that surrounds the embed. The problem is that the code occasionally doesn't fire, and this only happens online, not on my computer. I think this is because it sometimes takes too mutch time to load the 15 embeds with a slow connection, maybe the code fires when the players aren't ready, or too late? well... I dont know. I tried wrapping the whole code in a SetTimout() thing, but no luck. Anybody have a solution? Help will be greatly appreciated!

CODE (PARTIALLY):

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player1;var player2;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
events: {
  'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange1
}
  });
  player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
events: {
  'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange2
}
  });

---- etc... (untill player 15)

function onPlayerStateChange1(event) {
if (event.data == 0) {
player2.playVideo();
};
if (event.data == 1) {
document.getElementById("redlow1").setAttribute("class", "hero-unit77");
document.getElementById("redhigh1").setAttribute("class", "hero-unit88");
};
if (event.data == 2 || event.data == 0 || event.data == 5) {
document.getElementById("redlow1").setAttribute("class", "hero-unit7");
document.getElementById("redhigh1").setAttribute("class", "hero-unit8");
};
}
function onPlayerStateChange2(event) {
if (event.data == 0) {
player3.playVideo();
};
if (event.data == 1) {
document.getElementById("redlow2").setAttribute("class", "hero-unit77");
document.getElementById("redhigh2").setAttribute("class", "hero-unit88");
};
if (event.data == 2 || event.data == 0 || event.data == 5) {
document.getElementById("redlow2").setAttribute("class", "hero-unit7");
document.getElementById("redhigh2").setAttribute("class", "hero-unit8");
};
}

---- etc... (untill player 15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work finnaly, the solution was using the onload function of the Yutube iframe like so:

```
<iframe onload="floaded1()" id="player1">
```

with this script:

```
function floaded1() {
             player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
             events: {
                'onStateChange': function (event) {
if (event.data == 0) {
player2.playVideo();
};
if (event.data == 1) {
document.getElementById("redlow1").setAttribute("class", "hero-unit77");
document.getElementById("redhigh1").setAttribute("class", "hero-unit88");
};
if (event.data == 2 || event.data == 0 || event.data == 5) {
document.getElementById("redlow1").setAttribute("class", "hero-unit7");
document.getElementById("redhigh1").setAttribute("class", "hero-unit8");
};
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may help you is to not use a different state change event listener for each player object. Instead, use a single listener for all of your players, as any state change event will also include a reference to the player that raised the event (in the 'target' attribute of the event object). First, in the 'events' parameter of each player creation function, bind the 'onReady' to a function that will load a reference to that player into a global object, and bind the 'onStateChange' all to the same function. Something like this (note: untested code written very late at night ... if you get errors you can't figure out, we'll work through them!):

```
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player1, player2;
  var players={};
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
     events: {
     'onReady': function() {
         players.['player1']=player1;
      }
     'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
     }
    });
    player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
     events: {
      'onReady': function() {
         players['player2']=player2;
      }
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange;
    }
  });
---- etc... (untill player 15)
```

Then, you can define the state change listener function, and use the event.target for reference:

```
onPlayerStateChange = function(event) {
 if (event.data == 0) {
  players[event.target.a.id].playVideo();
 };
 if (event.data == 1) { 
   document.getElementById(event.target.a.id.replace("player","redlow")).setAttribute("class", "hero-unit77");
document.getElementById(event.target.a.id.replace("player","redhigh")).setAttribute("class", "hero-unit88");
};
if (event.data == 2 || event.data == 0 || event.data == 5) {
   document.getElementById(event.target.a.id.replace("player","redlow")).setAttribute("class", "hero-unit7");
   document.getElementById(event.target.a.id.replace("player","redhigh")).setAttribute("class", "hero-unit8");
};
 };
```

Comment: THNX so mutch! problem with this is that when event.data=0, it replays the video that is already playing, for example: i need it player1 to +1 to player2, and player9 to +1 to player10. (And komma was missing after the 'OnReady' event :) )

Comment: and unfortunately it still very inconsistent (i've tried without the 'players[event.target.a.id].playVideo();' part).